# How to test cakephp application with jmeter

Tags: cakephp, jmeter

I have a cakephp application and I want to test it with JMeter, In the front of my application, we need to log in first, we can access the page after login. I have write the parameter name and value in JMeter so the JMeter can login automatically. I write it like this :

name:                          value:

```
data[User][username]           admin
data[User][password]           12345
```

and after that, I add two HTTP Requests, the first one is to access the default page, and the second is to access an index form. But when I run the application, I find this in the result :

```
2012/07/06 15:49:33 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2012/07/06 15:49:33 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*) 
2012/07/06 15:49:33 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 5 threads for group J Meter User. 
2012/07/06 15:49:33 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
2012/07/06 15:49:33 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: J Meter User 1-1 
2012/07/06 15:49:33 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All threads have been started 
2012/07/06 15:49:33 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: J Meter User 1-1 
2012/07/06 15:49:33 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Ending thread J Meter User 1-1 
2012/07/06 15:49:33 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: J Meter User 1-2 
2012/07/06 15:49:33 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: J Meter User 1-2 
2012/07/06 15:49:33 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Ending thread J Meter User 1-2 
2012/07/06 15:49:33 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: J Meter User 1-3 
2012/07/06 15:49:33 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: J Meter User 1-3 
2012/07/06 15:49:33 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Ending thread J Meter User 1-3 
2012/07/06 15:49:33 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: J Meter User 1-4 
2012/07/06 15:49:33 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: J Meter User 1-4 
2012/07/06 15:49:33 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Ending thread J Meter User 1-4 
2012/07/06 15:49:34 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: J Meter User 1-5 
2012/07/06 15:49:34 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: J Meter User 1-5 
2012/07/06 15:49:34 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Ending thread J Meter User 1-5 
2012/07/06 15:49:34 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2012/07/06 15:49:34 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*) 
2012/07/06 15:49:34 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Test has ended on host null
```

can someone tell me how to access the login form in cakephp with JMeter so I can do the load test in my application?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter log file isn't very informative, I'd recommend using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to visualize responses and debug your script as it can even render HTML.

For correct simulation of login event refer to [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) guide. You will have different dynamic parameters in your cakephp application, however general approach should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would need to know on which url you're logging in. If you don't know it's in your page source in `form` element.

And check the form `method` type. It's usually `POST`. When user logs in usually something is stored at his/her side maybe in cookie such as `SESSION_ID` or what not I'm not sure how cakePHP works.

So create a `Http sampler` to post to that url from form and extract the session id value.

And you'll need `Http Cookied Manager` so you can store your session_id or whatever identifier you use in order to proceed as logged user.

So naturally all requests with that session id which you've authorized before can access the protected pages unless you log out.

That pretty much sums it, shouldn't be too hard.